# Browser suggestions to auto complete personal information

Tags: html, browser

When I visit some sites and enter information such as First name, Last name, Email, Phone Number, etc (*assuming I've done it before*)... The browser seems smart enough to suggest the appropriate values for fields I'm entering data for.

What are the standards/markup behind these fields that enable (*or assist*) the browsers in correlating these details to cached values?

In this case I *do not mean* revisiting the same form on the same site, but different forms on different sites.

**Edit**

This appears to relate to things such as the Internet Explorer's `VCARD_NAME` attribute and the HTML 5 `autocomplete` attribute. With that said, I still can't find any guidance on how to embrace autocompletion for things like *first names*, *emails*, etc... Do I set the `name` attribute to some specific value on input elements... or maybe the `class`? I'm just not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little homework, it would appear there is no single standard for this. The HTML5 spec addresses *autocomplete* as a feature a **User Agent** *may* provide, but does not go so far as defining any further recommendations or guidance

> ...User agents sometimes have features for helping users fill forms
>   in, for example prefilling the user's address based on earlier user
>   input...

It would also seem that much of the community tries to suppress this for security/privacy reasons. In the end, it would appear this is not something you can rely on from browsers, and some would say you should never implement this for personal information.